# Material2: extending MatInput

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I'm trying to make Material 2's `MatInput` listen to a service. I can't do that, of course, so I thought I could extend it instead. But no matter what I do, Angular tells me:

> Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl. Did you
>   forget to add matInput to the native input or textarea element?

I kept adding parts of the original `MatInput`. Here's what I have now? Am I going down the wrong rabbit hole?

```
import { Platform}                                    from "@angular/cdk/platform";
import { Directive, ElementRef, Optional, Renderer2 } from "@angular/core";
import { FormGroupDirective, NgControl, NgForm }      from "@angular/forms";
import { ErrorStateMatcher, MatInput}                 from "@angular/material";

import { ReactorService }                             from "./thrc-react.service";

@Directive({
  selector: `input[responsiveMatInput], textarea[responsiveMatInput]`,
  exportAs: 'responsiveMatInput',
  host: {
    'class': 'mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control',
    // Native input properties that are overwritten by Angular inputs need to be synced with
    // the native input element. Otherwise property bindings for those don't work.
    '[attr.id]': 'id',
    '[placeholder]': 'placeholder',
    '[disabled]': 'disabled',
    '[required]': 'required',
    '[readonly]': 'readonly',
    '[attr.aria-describedby]': '_ariaDescribedby || null',
    '[attr.aria-invalid]': 'errorState',
    '(blur)': '_focusChanged(false)',
    '(focus)': '_focusChanged(true)',
    '(input)': '_onInput()',
  },
})
export class ResponsiveInputComponent extends MatInput {
  constructor(protected _elementRef: ElementRef,
              protected _renderer: Renderer2,
              protected _platform: Platform,
              @Optional() public ngControl: NgControl,
              @Optional() protected _parentForm: NgForm,
              @Optional() protected _parentFormGroup: FormGroupDirective,
              _defaultErrorStateMatcher: ErrorStateMatcher,
              reactor: ReactorService, // My service, in case it weren't obvious.
  ) {
    super(_elementRef, _renderer, _platform, ngControl,_parentForm,
      _parentFormGroup, _defaultErrorStateMatcher);
    reactor.reactor$.subscribe(event => {
        console.log('Received.', event);
        // My custom code...
      }
    );

  }
}
```

Comment: well did you put `matInput` for the field, like suggested by error?

Comment: Actually, no. I just replaced it with my replacement directive. But I need my service to call a method on `MatInput`, so adding the original one will not help. I need to add it through the extend class.

Comment: Can I see the HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following the `@Directive` decorator:

`providers: [{provide: MatFormFieldControl, useExisting: ResponsiveInputComponent}]`

Comment: Many years later, this was helpful.  Thank you!